# Does the function need to be Lipschitz or is Lebesgue integrable enough?

Tags: lebesgue-integral, lipschitz-functions

Let $f:[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$, $\mathbb{Z}_n =\{0,1,\dots,n-1\}$ and $\delta >0$.

Which is the least I can assume about $f$ so that

\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
    \left| \frac{1}{n} \sum_{ x \in \mathbb{Z}_n} f(\tfrac{x}{n})  - \int_{[0,1]}f(u)  \ du \right| \leq  \delta 
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
for sufficiently large $n$?

I know for a fact that if $f$ is [Lipschitz continuous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lipschitz_continuity) with constant $K$, then the inequality holds as

\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
    \left| \frac{1}{n} \sum_{ x \in \mathbb{Z}_n} f(\tfrac{x}{n})  - \int_{[0,1]}f(u) \ du \right| & = \left| \frac{1}{n} \sum_{ x \in \mathbb{Z}_n} f(\tfrac{x}{n}) - \sum_{x \in \mathbb{Z}_n}\int_{\tfrac{x}{n}}^{\tfrac{x+1}{n}}f(u) \ du \right|   \\
    & = \left| \frac{1}{n} \sum_{ x \in \mathbb{Z}_n}  \int_{\tfrac{x}{n}}^{\tfrac{x+1}{n}} (f(\tfrac{x}{n})  - f(u) ) \ du \right|\\
    & \leq  \sum_{ x \in \mathbb{Z}_n}  \int_{\tfrac{x}{n}}^{\tfrac{x+1}{n}} \left|f(\tfrac{x}{n}) - f(u)\right| \ du \\
    & \leq  \sum_{ x \in \mathbb{Z}_n}  \int_{\tfrac{x}{n}}^{\tfrac{x+1}{n}} K \left| \tfrac{x}{n}- u \right| \ du \leq K \sum_{ x \in \mathbb{Z}_n}  \int_{\tfrac{x}{n}}^{\tfrac{x+1}{n}} \tfrac{1}{n} \ du\\
    & = K \sum_{ x \in \mathbb{Z}_n}  \tfrac{1}{n^2}= \frac{K}{n}.
\end{split}
\end{equation*}

So I guess my question is: Can I assume some (relevant) weaker condition about $f$ so that the inequality holds? In particular, is the inequality true if $f$ is just integrable?

Comment: I think absolute Riemann integrability is sufficient. Lebesgue integrability is *definitely* not (consider a function with support $\mathbb{Q}$ for example).

Comment: If you're willing to work modulo nullsets (so that a function with support $\mathbb{Q} \cap [0,1]$ is the $0$ function) then the answer is yes for any $L^1$ "function". If you restrict to continuous functions, the result is still true, but now is true on-the-nose instead of up to nullsets (this also excludes the $\mathbb{Q} \cap [0,1]$ counterexample). If you like, I can write this up as an answer, but the idea is to use the density of smooth functions in $L^1([0,1])$.

Comment: If $f$ is continuous then the classical, the Riemann, and the Lebesgue integral of $f$ are equal and the proposition is true.